# Configuration Manager app settings return nothing from the app.config

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a windows app in which there are few keys configured as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>
        <!-- <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>-->
        <add key ="IntervalMinutes" value ="1"/>
        <add key ="ScheduledTime" value ="18:41"/>
        <add key ="mainConnection" value ="hidden"/>
        <add key ="tbl_ref_date" value ="2017-01-11 11:46:38.833"/>
        <add key ="trg_ref_date" value ="2017-01-09 19:03:08.840"/>
        <add key ="ScheduledTime" value ="18:41"/>

    </appSettings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

But in my code behind I tried to access a value, but it returns nothing.

Also I tried this which returns 0

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Length
```

Why this happening..

This is my project structure

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be anything wrong here. Could you add the code used to retrieve the value? Did you try to clean the project and remove anything in the BIN\DEBUG folder?

Comment: @Steve System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Length returns 0 or when we try to get any key values using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Mode") returns nothing

Comment: Did you check if the config file is present in the BIN\DEBUG folder and if it has the proper settings?

Comment: It was actually in the root of the project. But as you suggested I duplicated it to the debug folder and tried.. Its still returns nothing